# Open an xml document in Internet Explorer using a relative path in C#

Tags: c#, xml, internet-explorer, relative-path, filepath

The code I have so far is this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "filename.xml");
```

It does launch internet explorer, but the URL shows: "http://filename.xml/" and of course can't be displayed.

The xml file is located in the bin/Debug folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the relative path was not providing the full path to internet explorer, so I had to use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", Path.GetFullPath("filename.xml"));
```

Make sure to add `using System.IO` to your program as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                     System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                     "filename.xml");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", path);
```

You should write the complete path to the file with "file:///" added in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but it was important to use a relative path, I just figured it out and will post a solution below.

Comment: Use GetCurrentDirectory method

Answer (score 0):

something like that would work

```
string sXmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "filename.xml");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", sXmlPath);
```